# 500 internal server error on heroku after adding image{(favicon) in my rails app assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

i'm running on Ruby 2.3.3 &
rails 5.1

i'm getting this from heroku logs =>

> ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "favicon/favicon.ico" is not present in the asset pipeline.):

folder path (assets/images/favicon/favicon.ico)

code in my application header:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon/favicon.ico' %>
```

It was working locally, but I got a 500 internal server error when I pushed it to heroku. i have run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and it's still not working.

Comment: Make sure that in that path the favicon exists when you push it to Heroku. I have had issues where a file will be @ /route1/route2 on local and when i push to heroku its route0/route1/route2

Comment: alright, thanks very much

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: Just to follow up on what @Chris said run `heroku logs --tail` and check what the error is if you saw that error while pushing to heroku, chances are that is not what is throwing the 500.